# BIGINT max 255 characters?

Tags: mysql, int

I need my integer column to be able to go up to 2000, so I made it `INT(2000)`, but it keeps saying;

> Display width out of range for column (max = 255)

I have tried using `MEDIUMINT(2000)` and `BIGINT(2000)`, but both give the same message.

Comment: I think that's the size of TINYINT, can you post a screenshot of your table structure in phpmyadmin?

Comment: show your code not only words

Comment: Do you need it to support 2000 characters or up to the number 2000? Integer columns are stored as binary so there is a limit as to how large of a number can be stored.

Comment: Use `int(4)`  and not `int(2000)`

Comment: Yes I need it to go up to the number 2000

Comment: Rethink why you need a 2000 digit integers. 10^2000 is moreally than the number of atoms in the universe. You can't possibly have an application that requires that large a number.

Comment: The number(size)  specified in an integer column in mysql only specifies the print length. It has no connection to the actual size of the column which is 4 or 8 bytes.

Comment: What value are you actually trying to write to the DB field that causes it to throw that error? Can you show us the query that throws the error and also show us the exact table structure.

Comment: @datasage: I don't think the finite nature of computer memory has anything to do with the integers being stored in binary form.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's a perfectly acceptable question. I wasn't sure what the right answer was until I read duskwuff below, and I've been working with mysql databases for over 10 years.

Comment: @worldofjr: Well the answer isn't strange, or esoteric, or surprising — this is common SQL knowledge that any first-year student should be taught. _But_ I concede I misread the question itself to begin with: I thought it needed some _details_, like a minimal testcase and a schema, which we usually insist upon. But then I realised that the OP's misunderstanding is kind of there in his wording, so (although I still think it could be vastly improved), I deleted my comment before your response. I do insist that it's unworthy of 5 upvotes in its current form, and remain surprised that it has them.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, I'm sure the 25 rep points will be used wisely!

Comment: @worldofjr: Here's hoping!

Answer (score 8):

The number used in a SQL type is the *width* of the type, not the maximum value. When used on a numeric type, it represents the maximum number of base-10 digits used to represent a value in that column: for instance, an `INT(5)` can represent any value up to 99999.

A number with a maximum value of 2000 can be stored in any numeric column with a width of 4 or greater. But don't worry about the width; just use a normal `INT` and let the database use whatever size is default for that type. (It will be more than 4, but that's OK.)

Answer (score 1):

BIGINT(255) Means a Big Integer with 255 digits.

And well , It's a very big number especially when the UNSIGNED flag is used.

BIGINT is mostly used for Id of something.

So i don't think that you need a number more than a 255-digit number.

Or if you do need , keep it in a string.